# Use safe_key in webform emails

Tags: emails

I want to be able to send the safe_key through the internal email.
The website was doing this before, and for some reason is not any longer.

I've tried %value[safe_key] and %safekey.
I read some information [here](http://drupal.org/node/749782), but no one seemed to have an answer that worked.
Is there another token that works? I saw %email[key] but was not sure that it would map right.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, the solution I found was here: https://drupal.org/node/1340010

If you are using webform v3.x, then you will need to apply patch #19.

If you are using webform v4.x, patch #22 (I have not tried this one).

For me, to apply the patch (on a Linux system), I did the following (adjust the first line to match where your webform module is):

```
cd /etc/drupal7/all/modules/webform
wget https://drupal.org/files/webform-1340010-19.patch
patch < webform-safe_key.patch
```

Then I had access to a new token called "%safe_key" that did exactly what I wanted (e.g. "%safe_key[field]" gave me the value of the safe_key in the email, rather than the display value.